# C++ with gradle

Tags: c++, gradle

In Gradle 1.10 Release notes http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/release-notes I see C++ build mentioned.

**How to set up C++ project to build with gradle?** (without IDE)

Suppose I have

```
ProjectFolder/hello.cpp
ProjectFolder/build.gradle
```

`hello.cpp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("Hello World!!!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**What should basic `build.gradle` be** for this C++ project?

UPDATE: I have already looked at [Chapter 72 of User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html) and 2 year old examples mentioned. They don't make it simpler but more complicated.

There is 1 file example with 6 lines. I haven't been touching C++ for 10 year and I just wanted quick start e.g. with GCC . (Not yet found)

Comment: [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) and samples in the full Gradle distribution should get you started.

Comment: All the information you need is here => http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html

Comment: And here => https://github.com/alkemist/gradle-cpp-demo

Comment: Those does not help for this Hello world example

Comment: @PaulVerest how is this one: https://github.com/alkemist/gradle-cpp-demo/blob/master/compiler-settings/build.gradle not really similar to what you want? just delete the additional compiler flags and the wrapper stuff.

Comment: Why does `hello.cpp` hold source code entirely written in [tag:c]?

Comment: Isn't C valid C++ code? Could be `cout << "Hello World!" << endl;` as well. I wonder all those documents above doesn't have hello world example, but a list of special cases, how to add that and that. It should be 2 files and link to how to install compiler.

Comment: I'm confused. This is still Stack Overflow. Please provide the buildfile you've tried and the error messages that occurred when you ran it.

Answer (score 30):

1. put this in build.gradle

   ```
   apply plugin: 'cpp'
   executables {
      hello {}
   }
   ```
2. put your source file in src/hello/cpp/say_hello.cpp
3. run 'gradle helloExecutable'
4. your executable should be built to build/binaries/helloExecutable/hello

Or, if you want your source in src/foo/bar then add

```
sources {
    hello {
      cpp {
        source {
            srcDir "src/foo/bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please also give option without moving sources.

Comment: The user guide show you how to configure the plugin if you want your sources in a different place. I will edit my answer.

Comment: This is not working for latest versions (above gradle 2.3+), for that, please use models.components solution posted here by Amnon Shochot!

Answer (score 12):

Starting on Gradle 2.3 there have been major changes to native-component builds and the `executables` and `libraries` containers are not available anymore. Citing [Gradle 2.3 Release notes](http://gradle.org/docs/current/release-notes#major-changes-to-incubating-'native-component'-and-'jvm-component'-plugins):

> ... the DSL for defining native executables and libraries has
>   fundamentally changed. **The executables and libraries containers have
>   been removed, and components are now added by type to the components
>   container owned by the model registry**. Another major change is that
>   source sets for a component are now declared directly within the
>   component definition, instead of being configured on the sources
>   block.

The updated Gradle code compatible with Gradle 2.3+ will therefore look like:

```
model {
  components {
    hello(NativeExecutableSpec) {
      sources {
        cpp {
          source {
            srcDir "src/foo/bar"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can learn more about the new model in Gradle user guide [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html).

Comment: I don't understand why they did these changes. For someone like, who just started learning gradle, it's just a nightmare to learn.

Answer (score 2):

This is another answer.
I am using Gradle 2.4.7. My source code is the standard C++ as in the following directory structure on Windows:

myproject

myproject\src

myproject\src\main.cpp

myproject\build.gradle

main.cpp is just a Hello world C++ program.

I have Visual Studio 2015. I like to use its C++ compiler for the standard C++ programs.

build.gradle is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'

model {
    components {
        main(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {   
                cpp {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src"
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    binaries {
        all {
            if (toolChain in VisualCpp) {
                cppCompiler.args "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt"
                linker.args "/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt\\x86"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The extra compiler option and linker option is due to some change in Visual studio 2015 from its previous versions. Without the options, you will get a compilation not able to finding corecrt.h or a linker error not able to finding libucrt.lib.

Hope this will help you to begin C++ compilation with Visual Studio 2015 quickly!!!