# How to build static library from C++ using NDK on Android using Android Studio with Gradle?

Tags: android, c++, gradle, android-ndk

I have a project written in C++ and I want to build a static library to be able to link against it in other projects. But Android Studio along with NDK produces only shared library objects which are for me not usable (I need static objects). I use gradle plugin to build the code.

While the code compiles I cannot find a way to get a "libname.a" file.

Anybody knows the magic behind this in Gradle ?

Comment: What makes you think you need static objects?  This can be somewhat problematic - please see the "Static runtimes" paragraph of the CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html in the NDK distribution's documentation folder.

Comment: We need static objects because we cannot have the library being loaded in runtime. Our solution is a very seucred module for authentication with remote server, thus we cannot have the libs lying around in a package - we need them compiled and inside the binary.

Comment: So, do I understand you correctly, that you don't want to create a gradle task for building the lib with `ndk-build`?

Comment: @super-qua - No - i want to use gradle to build static libs. But at the end we need to have a shared object because from what I've read it seems that we cannot add static library into android apk.

Answer (score 0):

While not well familiar with the NDK Gradle supports building native static libraries. You can see an example in **[C++ with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059516/c-with-gradle)** or learn more about it in gradle user guide **[Native Binaries chapter](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html)**.

Comment: NDK builds aren't normally done directly under gradle, but rather under the NDK's own makefile-macro build system, with gradle ideally setting up the configuration files for that (or more often these days, ignoring the user's attempt and setting its own undesired defaults).   Unless one is going to try to export a cross toolchain from the NDK and do the build step-by-step with gradle invoking that gcc, the question is practically about using the NDK, and only secondarily about keeping gradle from interfering with that.

Comment: Exactly - the ndk gives us the ability to produce static libs fairly simple. Gradle in Android Studio can be injected with NDK script and this can create a static lib. But this is a hack and I personally don't like to use some tools in a way they were not meant to be used. For now we only build the libs using ndk-build invoked from 'JNI' folder of the android studio project.