# From C++ To Java - What is Gradle

Tags: java, c++, gradle, intellij-idea

I´m coding a few years in C++, Python .., but now I would like to learn Java. So I learned the basics, but I´m a little bit confused about Java Compilers. 
So what in purpose does Gradle? Right, it is compiling my Java files to .class files in bytecode, that can be interpreted directly or transferred into machine code when running the code.

But why I should use Gradle? Is it a Virtual Enviroment like Venv in Pycharm?

In Intellij I am able to choose, when I create a new Project, between a Java Project or a Gradle Project. So I´m a little bit confused how the Java Project works. Which Java Compiler is used for a common Java Project?

In a nutshell I want to know, when I should use Gradle or when I should use Standard Java Project, and how the Standard Java Project Java Compiler works in comparison to Gradle.

In my opinion it is like a comparison between G++ and CMake in C-Compilers yet. Is that for basic understanding a correct assumption?

Thanks for your help to a newbie to Java Programming ;-)

Comment: Have a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059516/c-with-gradle. I think as C++ developer you would also end up using Gradle

Comment: An advice (based on personal experience) - start with Maven instead of Gradle. Maven is easier and will teach you to structure your project in a standard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you are free to use the command line compiler (g++ or cl) as you wish, and run the compiled application afterwards. In Java, you can do the same (compile a class with [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), and run compiled programs with `java`). But, as your project grows, as you import more dependencies and libraries, it may become a challenge to manage all the compilation details. So you use a build management system like CMake. CMake still uses whatever C++ compiler you've got behind the scenes even if it sets certain things up for you.

Like C++ and Cmake, Java presents a lot of options for more complex build management, and it follows the same philosophy. Gradle is one management system. [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) is another popular choice. The key difference between these systems and CMake is that unlike CMake, where you usually download, configure, and install the dependencies yourself, Gradle and Maven will do it for you. They still use the Java compiler behind the scenes, but automate a lot of tasks for you. If you create a Java project without Gradle or Maven, you'll have to download, install and configure dependencies yourself to some extent- IntelliJ does take care of some aspects of that.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is a general purpose build management system. Like Cmake it allows you to create different tasks (e.g. build task, clean, etc.). But Gradle also supports the automatic download and configuration of dependencies or other libraries.
You should check out [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Gradle/article.html) introduction.